# Best practice on reading and writing to a persistent Volume in a live Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I am designing a Kubernetes system which will require storing audio files. To do this I would like to setup a persistent storage volume making use of a stateful set.

I have found a few tutorials on how to set something like this up, but I am unsure once I have created it how to read/write the files. What would be the best approach to do this. I will be using a flask app, but if I could just get a high level approach then I can find the exact libraries myself.

Comment: The same way like you read/write to files in any other directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not acknowledging on facts how it should be implemented programming wise and the specific tuning for dealing with audio files, you can use your `Persistent Volume` the same as you would read/write data to a directory (as correctly pointed by user @zerkms in the comments).

Answering this specific part of the question:

> but I am unsure once I have created it how to read/write the files.

Assuming that you've created your `StatefulSet` in a following way:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: ubuntu-sts
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ubuntu # has to match .spec.template.metadata.labels
  serviceName: "ubuntu"
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ubuntu
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: ubuntu
        image: ubuntu
        command:
        - sleep 
        - "infinity" 
        volumeMounts:
        - name: audio-volume
          mountPath: /audio 
  volumeClaimTemplates: 
  - metadata:
      name: audio-volume
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: standard
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Take a look on below part (it's showing where your `Volume` will be mounted):

```
        volumeMounts:
        - name: audio-volume
          mountPath: /audio # <-- HERE!
```

> Disclaimer!
>
> This example is having the 1:1 `Pod` to `Volume` relation. If your use case is different you will need to refer to the Kubernetes documentation about `accessModes`.

You can `exec` into this `Pod` to look how you can further develop your application:

- `$ kubectl exec -it ubuntu-sts-0 -- /bin/bash`
- `$ echo "Hello from your /audio directory!" > /audio/hello.txt`
- `$ cat /audio/hello.txt`

```sh
root@ubuntu-sts-0:/# cat /audio/hello.txt 
Hello from your /audio directory!
```

---

> A side note!
>
> If it happens that you are using the cloud-provider managed Kubernetes cluster like `GKE`, `EKS` or `AKS`, please refer to it's documentation about storage options.

I encourage you to check the official documentation on `Persistent Volumes`:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Storage: Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)*

Also, please take a look on documentation regarding `Statefulset`:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Workloads: Controllers: Statefulset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Guru99.com: Reading and writing files in Python](https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html)*